# How can I render angle brackets <> in wordpress blog page

Tags: wordpress, brackets

I'm new to WordPress, I just started a blog on it a few days ago and my contents contain code blocks. The problem I'm having is that I have some code that contains Generics like JpaRepository<Customer, Long> But the <> could not be rendered when I view the blog page. How can I fix this problem, please, any suggestion is appreciated.

The output on the blog post:
[This is what is displayed on the blog page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OW1nT.png)

The blog post can be viewed [here](https://fixdecode.com/2022/02/08/spring_framework/spring-boot-rest-api-example/) for a clear understanding of the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try this php native function:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php

and here is a live example

https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_htmlentities.asp

Comment: do you have any idea of any plugin that I can install to take care of this problem rather than adding code manually? Because there are going to be other users that will be posting code solutions here from different locations too. @Francesco

Comment: no, but you can make a child theme and use the functions.php file for this this kind of necessities https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/ and https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/#using-functions-php

Comment: Ok, thanks I will go through the links and see how it goes. Thanks @Francesco